# Apostrophe issue when inserting into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I have a script where I submit some fields that get entered into a MySQL database when I submit it now it goes through successfully but never gets inserted into the database if one of the fields has an apostrophe. What can I modify to get this to work?

```
if ($_POST) {
$name = trim($_POST['your_name']);
$email = trim($_POST['your_email']);
$answers = $_POST['answers'];
$i = 0;
foreach ($answers as $a) {
    if (trim($a))
        $i++;
}

if ($name && $email && $i >= 40) {
    $array = array();
    $q = mysql_query("select * from fields");
    while($f = mysql_fetch_array($q))
        $array[$f['label']] = $answers[$f['ID']];

    $array = serialize($array);
    $time = time();
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $token = md5($time);

    $result = mysql_query("insert into data (submit_name, submit_email, submit_data, submit_confirm, submit_time, submit_ip, submit_token) 
        values ('$name', '$email', '$array', '0', '$time', '$ip', '$token')");
```

Comment: This is why the `mysql_query` function should probably be removed from PHP. Whenever possible, which is almost **always**, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). You have no excuse to be putting user-entered text directly into your SQL.

Comment: The core dev team desperately wants to kill mysql/mysqli but there are **so many** horribly outdated "tutorials" on the net and it would break **so much** existing garbage code.

Comment: I've been watching the MySQL tag here more often and I am absolutely horrified at how blindingly ignorant people are to SQL escaping. It's like they don't even bother to mention it. In a just world, writing code like this would be a **capital crime**.

Comment: This wasn't something I wrote, but i will inform the person who wrote it how bad it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), as this will both fix your apostrophe issue and at least partly help avoid SQL injection attacks.  If you don't want to get your hands dirty with PHP's built-in PDO library, you might consider a Database Abstraction Layer (DBAL).  [ADODB](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) is an example.

Comment: Any pointers on where to put it within my script? Sorry, I'm a noob over here and I had this script written by someone else in the first place.

Comment: @kcray: You'd wrap every single user-supplied string with that function before you added it to your query.

Comment: Do you have a few minutes? Could you contact me real quick? impactfactor1[at]gmail[dot]com

Answer (score 3):

You need to [escape characters with special meaning in MySQL in your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

The quick and **dirty** way to improve your code would be to pass all your strings through [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) before inserting them into your string of SQL.

The better approach would be to switch away from `mysql_query` to something that allows the use of [bound parameters (preferably with prepared statements)](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: Is there a simple stand-alone ORM for PHP, or are they all bundled into things like CakePHP or CodeIgniter?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there wasn't, but I try to avoid PHP so I don't know.

Comment: Any pointers on where to put it within my script? Sorry, I'm a noob over here and I had this script written by someone else in the first place.

Comment: @tadman: People seem to like Doctrine 2 - http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/en

Comment: Anywhere between populating the variables and using them in the string you pass to `mysql_query`